# Как удалить последний TR из таблицы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Почему `length` выдает `0`?

`.list tr` - написать не могу так как могут быть вложенные таблицы

```js
console.log($('.list > tr').length);

if($('.list > tr').length > 5) $('.list > tr:last-child').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list">
  <tr><td>data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 8</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Учите html) Браузер таблицам дорисовывает тело (<tbody>) если вы это не указываете сами в коде, А Вы выбираете только по первому уровню вложенности `.list > tr`, хотя по факту получается table tbody tr

Comment: Можно убрать `>` из селектора, что будет означать - искать все элементы tr в элементе с классом list, но учтите, что в случае вложенности таблиц, строки из дочерней таблицы также попадут в результирующий набор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
console.log($('.list > tbody > tr').length);

while ($('.list > tbody > tr').length > 5) 
  $('.list > tbody > tr:last-child').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list">
  <tr><td>data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 8</td></tr>
</table>
```

```js
let rows = document.querySelector('.list').rows;
console.log(rows.length);

while (rows.length > 5) 
  rows[rows.length - 1].remove();
```

```html
<table class="list">
  <tr><td>data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 8</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Народ даже в devtools не заглядывает - сразу на SO :)

Comment: @UModeL а что тут девтулс сказал бы? Дело весь в селекторе >

Comment: @UModeL, ,Вот блин, точно) я и забыл что браузер `tbody` и `thead` сам подставляет, нарушает он мои права)

Comment: @InDevX: Ну, правильную разметку подсказал бы, например.

Comment: @InDevX, в девтулсе кстати нет tbody если таблица генерируется автоматически через js

Comment: @Squeli47 а я про девтулс ничего не говорил, это не мне комментарий)

Comment: @UModeL у меня ff de последняя версия - не показывает инспектор tbody

Comment: @InDevX: FF87 - `tbody` присутствует в инспекторе. Как и в Chrome89.

Comment: цикл излишен `$('.list > tbody > tr').slice(5).remove();`